# Access Json data in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

What will be the proper way to access the nested elements of this json file in angular?

Using $http in controller

```
 $http.get('app/api.json')
  .success(function(data){
    $scope.feeds = data;
  });
```

api.json

```js
{
  "feed": {
    "data": [{
        "story": "test story",
        "updated_time": "2016-06-05T17:17:49+0000",
        "id": "1"
      }, {
        "message": "jkhkjhkhjlkhk",
        "updated_time": "2015-05-08T07:23:14+0000",
        "id": "2"
      }

    ],
  }
}
```

the view

```
<div ng-repeat="feed in feeds">{{feed.data.id}}</div>
```

Right now I am more concerned with accessing the id's which are common, I see trouble when coming to display the story or messages  field since they are different.

PS: I am getting info from a facebook group through the graph api

Comment: `feed.data` is an array. You will have to loop over it. Try `feed.data[0].id`

Comment: worked! But returned only the first one.  How do I make it return all instead of just one element in the array?

Comment: I have added sample in answer. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I came across that, mine had to do accessing nested objects and arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, `feed.data` is an array and you will have to loop over it.

#### [Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/uz5ncxdo/)

```js
function myCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.d = {
    "feed": {
      "data": [{
          "story": "test story",
          "updated_time": "2016-06-05T17:17:49+0000",
          "id": "1"
        }, {
          "message": "jkhkjhkhjlkhk",
          "updated_time": "2015-05-08T07:23:14+0000",
          "id": "2"
        }

      ],
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <ul ng-repeat="o in d.feed.data">
      <li>{{o.id}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly that! Thank you!